# how to remove the ssl error from modernbill api installation

Tags: php

i want to installed the modernbill on my localhost,
i got this error on the installation phase,

> - You MUST have (SSL-enabled PHP cURL for faster secure remote API
>     queries [you do not], or SSL-enabled CLI cURL for secure remote API
>     queries [you do not]) [you do not].
>
>   - You SHOULD have SSL-enabled PHP cURL for faster secure remote API queries [you do not].
>   - You SHOULD have the "openssl" extension loaded for asynchronous secure remote API queries [you do not].
>   - You MAY have the "sysvshm" extension loaded for Unix performance optimizations [you do not].
>   - You MAY have the "sysvsem" extension loaded for Unix performance optimizations [you do not].

i enable the ssl and cURL module from ,y wamp server,
and also remove the ; from extention=php.curl file
but i got the abou=ve error,
i search for it the whole day but unable to solve the sain problem
please help me

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart your WAMP server after installing cURL and removing the ; ? Those changes don't take effect until the server is restarted.

Please provide a link to the output of phpinfo(), and possibly a link the the system requirements for the version of modernbill you're using.

To get information about your PHP installation, create a new script and view the results in your browser.

**phpinfo.php**

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Comment: how i phpinfo() changes made,please help @preinheimer

Comment: I've updated the post to include details on how to get your phpinfo() information.